# How to differ two uploads in one form with same upload handling?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, plugins

I have already created a form for my plugin, and it has two upload fields; one for an image and one for a zip-file. They are both using the same upload handler, and I want to save the attachment ID's to the database. The problem is that they use the same upload handler, so the value of the variable with the attachment ID will always be the last upload field. How is the best way to do this? Save in array (first index is first field, second index is second field)? Two upload handler is probably a bit overkill. Any ideas how to solve this in a good way?

This is the function that handles the upload:

```
function releases_action(){
    global $wpdb;

    // Upload cover
     $uploadfiles = $_FILES['uploadfiles'];

      if (is_array($uploadfiles)) {

        foreach ($uploadfiles['name'] as $key => $value) {

          // look only for uploded files
          if ($uploadfiles['error'][$key] == 0) {

            $filetmp = $uploadfiles['tmp_name'][$key];

            //clean filename and extract extension
            $filename = $uploadfiles['name'][$key];

            // get file info
            // @fixme: wp checks the file extension....
            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );
            $filetitle = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) );
            $filename = $filetitle . '.' . $filetype['ext'];
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            /**
             * Check if the filename already exist in the directory and rename the
             * file if necessary
             */
            $i = 0;
            while ( file_exists( $upload_dir['path'] .'/' . $filename ) ) {
              $filename = $filetitle . '_' . $i . '.' . $filetype['ext'];
              $i++;
            }
            $filedest = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;

            /**
             * Check write permissions
             */
            if ( !is_writeable( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
              $this->msg_e('Unable to write to directory %s. Is this directory writable by the server?');
              return;
            }

            /**
             * Save temporary file to uploads dir
             */
            if ( !@move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filedest) ){
              $this->msg_e("Error, the file $filetmp could not moved to : $filedest ");
              continue;
            }

            $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
              'post_title' => $filetitle,
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );

            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filedest );
            require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php' );
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filedest );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
          }
        }

}
```

As I said, as both upload fields uses the same function, the $attach_ID variable will be the value of the latest upload.

Comment: where in the database do you want them to save or do you just want the values returned?

Comment: Right now I save the $attach_id to the field in the database. But, as I wrote, the $attach_id will contain the value of the latest uploaded file.

Comment: You are using a foreach loop so you can save the id within the loop and it will have the correct value for that loop. Look in the answer i included a note as to where to place your code.

Comment: So I should save it to the database within the function? Wouldn't that give me two database connections for one form? There must be an easier approach? Maybe saving them to an array?

Comment: the function you are using already uses at least 2 database connections. I dont know where you want to save the id's and how you want to pull it but ill put another bit below for array...

Answer (score 1):

```
function releases_action(){
global $wpdb;

// Upload cover
 $uploadfiles = $_FILES['uploadfiles'];

  if (is_array($uploadfiles)) {

    foreach ($uploadfiles['name'] as $key => $value) {

      // look only for uploded files
      if ($uploadfiles['error'][$key] == 0) {

        $filetmp = $uploadfiles['tmp_name'][$key];

        //clean filename and extract extension
        $filename = $uploadfiles['name'][$key];

        // get file info
        // @fixme: wp checks the file extension....
        $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );
        $filetitle = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) );
        $filename = $filetitle . '.' . $filetype['ext'];
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        /**
         * Check if the filename already exist in the directory and rename the
         * file if necessary
         */
        $i = 0;
        while ( file_exists( $upload_dir['path'] .'/' . $filename ) ) {
          $filename = $filetitle . '_' . $i . '.' . $filetype['ext'];
          $i++;
        }
        $filedest = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;

        /**
         * Check write permissions
         */
        if ( !is_writeable( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
          $this->msg_e('Unable to write to directory %s. Is this directory writable by the server?');
          return;
        }

        /**
         * Save temporary file to uploads dir
         */
        if ( !@move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filedest) ){
          $this->msg_e("Error, the file $filetmp could not moved to : $filedest ");
          continue;
        }

        $attachment = array(
          'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
          'post_title' => $filetitle,
          'post_content' => '',
          'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );

        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filedest );
        require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php' );
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filedest );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
        // $ids[]= $attach_id;
        // save $attach id here, its correct for this loop, on the next loop it will be different and so on..
      }
    }

return $ids; // or save here serialize() maybe needed depending on how you are saving. 
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the solution can be reached with this approach. Cause I guess that the first upload will be placed in the first index, second upload in the second index etc. I need for example the first index to be empty if there isn't any upload in the first upload field. Pretty hard to explain, but you did a good attempt. I see now that I simply need to rethink my code a bit.

Comment: if the $attach id fails it will return 0. so you can test for that in your logic for whatever you want to do. or you could do something like if($attachid) {$ids[]=$attachid} else {$ids=""} but rethink about what you want to do and post back if you have any q's